# Envio de Email no Servidor

Tags: php, html, email

Estou tentando criar uma página que envia emails porém não estou os recebendo...

Teria alguma coisa que deve verificar ?

Segue código que utilizo para enviar...

```
<?php
$message = "Testando outros remetentes, para facilitar a resposta";
$headers = 'From: suporte@dominio.com.br';

if (mail('suporte@dominio.com.br', 'Teste', $message, $headers)) {
    print('Funcionou');
}else{ 
    print('Nao Funcionou...');
};
?>
```

Esse email do FROM  deve estar cadastrado no meu servidor do painel de hospedagem ou posso utilizar um genérico ?

Comment: Está a mandar de um servidor local?

Comment: @Miguel Não, de um servidor de Hospedagem pago

Answer (score 1):

Experimente assim, o problema muitas vezes são os headers default, deve defini-los, principalmente o `From` e o `Reply-To`

```
$body = 'corpo da mensagem';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Miguel <miguel@miguel.pt>" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: miguel@miguel.pt" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if(!mail('suporte@dominio.com.br', 'teste', $body, $headers)) 
{
    echo 'Erro';
}
else {
    echo 'YAY';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio ! Porém a mensagem de "Erro" é exibida, saberia o que pode estar ocorrendo ?

Comment: Escreva `print_r(error_get_last());` antes do `echo 'Erro';` e veja o que imprime

Comment: Nenhuma mensagem é exibida... apenas o Erro

Comment: Escreva isto no inicio do ficheiro e volte a tentar:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);    . Serve para vermos os error de php

Comment: Nada... acredito que possa ser a porta, como defino uma porta no PHP mail ?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793716/how-to-set-port-and-host-for-php-function-mail